# Call image from within a javascript function?

Tags: javascript

On [this site](http://sleep.fm/coming-soon/), when user sets alarm sound and time, under "Set Alarm," their chosen time and alarm sound appears.

I want instead of for example, 2:00pm [X] (alarm set - weather) or 2:00pm [X] (alarm set - rooster) I want the image of weather or rooster to appear instead of it printing text.

This is the function that is printing the text

```
function getAlarmName(ind){
    if(ind==4) return "weather";
    else if(ind==3) return "flight";
    else if(ind==1) return "time";
    else return "rooster";
}
```

I tried removing "weather," and "flight," for example and adding instead image/weather.jpg  and image/flight.jpg, but that is not the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
function getAlarmName(ind){
    if(ind==4) return "<img src='image/weather.jpg' />";
    else if(ind==3) return "<img src='image/flight.jpg' />";
    else if(ind==1) return "<img src='image/time.jpg' />";
    else return "<img src='image/rooster.jpg' />";
}
```

Comment: Thank you i had tried something similar but it did not work.  Im somewhat a noob at javascript and I was using quotes around src image and not  '    '

Comment: Glad to be of help. I 'd suggest you take a look at jQuery. I use it almost everywhere, and it's sure to help you in the future...